# Unity2D: Can't balance wall jump forces

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My intention is to make my character wall jump/climb/slide, I got the sliding part working fine, but if he jumps while wall sliding, he should "bounce" back to the wall, the problem is that I can't balance the forces. In all tutorial I saw, it is simply a matter of detecting if the character is wall sliding, and if he is and he jumps, then you add a force oposite to the wall.

This is not working for me, because if I add enough force to make him jump, he goes way too fast and the player can barely see he jumped, he just sees that the character is now higher on the wall. If I add a smaller amount of force, it isn't enough to make a considerable jump and the player would have to hit space a thousand times to make him go up a few centimeters on the wall.

Any help is appreciated, I already tried a lot of things, even tried to freeze the controls, set gravity scale to 0 and make the character fo to the right points using MoveTowards, that is how desperate I am.

I'm also really new to Unity so I might be missing something really simple.

Here is a gif showing the character's behavior:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/miMvV.jpg

And here is the relevant parts of my character's script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TheBot : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public int jumpForce;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public Transform meleeCheck;
    public Transform bulletSpawner;
    public LayerMask layerGround;
    public float meleeCoolDown;
    public float meleeDamage;

    private Rigidbody2D body;
    private Animator anim;
    private Dash dashController;
    private Shooter shotController;
    private float unloadWaitingTime = 3;
    private float idleGunTime = 0;

    private bool facingRight = true;
    private bool onGround = true;
    private bool jumping = false;
    private bool attacking = false;
    private bool dead = false;
    private bool isGunLoaded = false;
    private bool isGunLoading = false;
    private bool isGunUnloading = false;
    private bool takingDamage = false;
    private bool dashing = false;
    private bool isWallSliding = false;

    private float wallJumpTime = 0f;
    private Vector3[] wallJumpControlPoint;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        dashController = GetComponent<Dash>();
        shotController = GetComponent<Shooter>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        PlayAnimations();
        CheckIfGrounded();
        checkIfWallSliding();
        dashing = dashController.IsDashing();

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && (onGround || isWallSliding)  && !isGunLoading && !jumping && !takingDamage){
            jumping = true;
            wallJumpControlPoint = new Vector3[3];
            wallJumpControlPoint[0] = body.position;
            wallJumpControlPoint[1] = new Vector3(body.position.x +4, body.position.y + 2);
            wallJumpControlPoint[2] = new Vector3(body.position.x, body.position.y + 4);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Melee") && !attacking && !isGunLoading){
            Attack();
        }
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Ranged") && !attacking  && !isGunLoading && onGround){
            Shoot();
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Dash") && !attacking && !isGunLoading && onGround){
            dashController.DashTo(facingRight? Dash.RIGHT : Dash.LEFT);
        }


        if(isGunLoaded){
            idleGunTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if (idleGunTime >= unloadWaitingTime){
                UnloadGun();
            }
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        if(!takingDamage){

            float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

            //while charachter is wall sliding, slowly fall
            if (isWallSliding){
                body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, -0.7f);
            }

            if(!dashing){
                if(onGround){
                    //if not dashing on on ground, walk with normal speed
                    body.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, body.velocity.y);
                } else {
                    //if character is not on ground, reduce the speed so he doesn't jump too far away
                    body.velocity = new Vector2(move * (speed * 0.7f), body.velocity.y);
                }
            }

            if((move < 0 && facingRight) || (move > 0 && !facingRight) ){
                //control direction character is facing
                Flip();
            }

            if (jumping){

                if(isWallSliding){
                    body.velocity = new Vector2(30, 20);
                } else {
                    body.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }

                if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
                    //if is moving while jumping, reduce jump height
                    body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, body.velocity.y*0.8f);
                }
                onGround = false;
                jumping = false;
            }       
        }
    }

    void CheckIfGrounded(){
        onGround = false;
        Collider2D[] collisionResults = new Collider2D[2];
        int objectsBeneath = Physics2D.OverlapBoxNonAlloc(groundCheck.position, new Vector2(0.9f, 0.3f), 0.0f, collisionResults, layerGround);
        for (int i=0; i <objectsBeneath; i++ ){
            if (!GameObject.ReferenceEquals(gameObject, collisionResults[i].gameObject)){
                onGround = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void checkIfWallSliding(){
        if (!onGround){
            RaycastHit2D[] ray = new RaycastHit2D[1];
            int totalRayHits = Physics2D.LinecastNonAlloc(bulletSpawner.position, body.position, ray, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("SolidGround"));
            bool wallFound = totalRayHits > 0 && ray[0].collider.gameObject.tag == "SolidGround";

            isWallSliding = wallFound && ( (facingRight && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) ||  (!facingRight && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))) ;
        } else {
            isWallSliding = false;
            if (body.velocity.y > 10){
                body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, 5);
            }
        }
    }


    public void Die(){
        dead = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: try putting more vertical and less horizontal force on your character. Also, you'll want to be sure that he force you add has the right positive or negative x component depending on which direction the wall is from the character.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I tried that, I don't think the problem is the amount of force. If add more vertical and less horizontal he still jumps too fast to be seen, and worse, if the player releases the arrow and don't come back to the wall, he jumps to the moon because. Also, I'm aware of the positive / negative force, but this way is simpler. I will use the correct forces once the wall jump is working to one direction.

Comment: What happens when you reset the y velocity then `AddForce` inside of `if(isWallSliding){`?  `body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, 0);` `body.AddForce(new Vector2(0.25 * jumpForce, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);`

Comment: Actually, why do you reset the vertical velocity to 5 here: `body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, 5);` ?

Comment: When I add the force he just jumps really fast, like in the gif. Answering you second comment: I reset the velocity to 5 because I was trying to set a limit speed so the player can see the character jumping, but that didn't work

Comment: I think the problem is that as soon as you leave the wall, pressing left towards the wall sets its horizontal velocity immediately to left and takes it directly into the wall, which sets its vertical velocity immediately to down. What you might want to do is change your wall slide slowdown code to be `if (isWallSliding && body.velocity.y < -0.7f){
                body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, -0.7f);` so when you go back to the wall you can still slide up a little bit even if touching the wall.  After that, then you can lower the force/velocity of walljump.

Comment: that didn't solve it either, I changed the if condition to: `if (isWallSliding && body.velocity.y < -0.7f)` [here](https://imgur.com/a/TMOeym7) is what happened (I also increased the jump force y so it would be easier to see). I think the problem is with the X axis, the Y is working fine, the problem is that the character jumps away from the wall way too fast

Comment: Did you lower the force/velocity of the walljump after making that change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've attempted before, you will need to reduce your horizontal jump acceleration/velocity on the jump.

When you wall jump, you'll be pressing towards the wall. And as your code is currently, while you are in the air, your horizontal velocity is set to be in the direction you press. This makes any horizontal movement from the wall jump very hard to see, unless it's large enough to push you very far in one frame.

This (as well as the change we discussed in the comments) is why your previous attempts with low walljump magnitudes didn't work.

To fix this, you have to change how your air control works. One way of going about it is making it add a clamped modifier to your horizontal velocity instead of setting it directly to the target velocity.

```
if(!dashing){
    if(onGround){
        //if not dashing on on ground, walk with normal speed
        body.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, body.velocity.y);
    } else {
        //if character is not on ground, reduce the speed so he doesn't jump too far away
        float airControlAccelerationLimit = 0.5f;  // Higher = more responsive air control
        float airSpeedModifier = 0.7f; // the 0.7f in your code, affects max air speed
        float targetHorizVelocity = move 
                * speed 
                * airSpeedModifier;  // How fast we are trying to move horizontally
        float targetHorizChange = targetHorizVelocity 
                - body.velocity.x; // How much we want to change the horizontal velocity
        float horizChange = Mathf.Clamp(
                targetHorizChange ,
                -airControlAccelerationLimit , 
                airControlAccelerationLimit ); // How much we are limiting ourselves 
                                               // to changing the horizontal velocity
        body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x + horizChange, body.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Here it is, in your code, along with making sure we only update velocity once OR use `AddForce` per `FixedUpdate` call. And we also change the wallsliding slowdown code to only activate if the player is about to go down faster than the wallslide speed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TheBot : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public int jumpForce;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public Transform meleeCheck;
    public Transform bulletSpawner;
    public LayerMask layerGround;
    public float meleeCoolDown;
    public float meleeDamage;

    private Rigidbody2D body;
    private Animator anim;
    private Dash dashController;
    private Shooter shotController;
    private float unloadWaitingTime = 3;
    private float idleGunTime = 0;

    private bool facingRight = true;
    private bool onGround = true;
    private bool jumping = false;
    private bool attacking = false;
    private bool dead = false;
    private bool isGunLoaded = false;
    private bool isGunLoading = false;
    private bool isGunUnloading = false;
    private bool takingDamage = false;
    private bool dashing = false;
    private bool isWallSliding = false;

    private float wallJumpTime = 0f;
    private Vector3[] wallJumpControlPoint;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        dashController = GetComponent<Dash>();
        shotController = GetComponent<Shooter>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        PlayAnimations();
        CheckIfGrounded();
        checkIfWallSliding();
        dashing = dashController.IsDashing();

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && (onGround || isWallSliding)  && !isGunLoading && !jumping && !takingDamage){
            jumping = true;
            wallJumpControlPoint = new Vector3[3];
            wallJumpControlPoint[0] = body.position;
            wallJumpControlPoint[1] = new Vector3(body.position.x +4, body.position.y + 2);
            wallJumpControlPoint[2] = new Vector3(body.position.x, body.position.y + 4);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Melee") && !attacking && !isGunLoading){
            Attack();
        }
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Ranged") && !attacking  && !isGunLoading && onGround){
            Shoot();
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Dash") && !attacking && !isGunLoading && onGround){
            dashController.DashTo(facingRight? Dash.RIGHT : Dash.LEFT);
        }


        if(isGunLoaded){
            idleGunTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if (idleGunTime >= unloadWaitingTime){
                UnloadGun();
            }
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        if(!takingDamage){

            float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

            //while charachter is wall sliding, slowly fall
            if (isWallSliding && !jumping && body.velocity.y < -0.7f){ 
                body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, -0.7f)
            }

            if(!dashing){
                if(onGround){
                    //if not dashing on on ground, walk with normal speed
                    body.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, body.velocity.y);
                } else {
                    //if character is not on ground, reduce the speed so he doesn't jump too far away
                    float airControlAccelerationLimit = 0.5f;  // Higher = more responsive air control
                    float airSpeedModifier = 0.7f; // the 0.7f in your code, affects max air speed
                    float targetHorizVelocity = move 
                            * speed 
                            * airSpeedModifier;  // How fast we are trying to move horizontally
                    float targetHorizChange = targetHorizVelocity 
                            - body.velocity.x; // How much we want to change the horizontal velocity
                    float horizChange = Mathf.Clamp(
                            targetHorizChange ,
                            -airControlAccelerationLimit , 
                            airControlAccelerationLimit ); // How much we are limiting ourselves 
                                                           // to changing the horizontal velocity
                    body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x + horizChange, body.velocity.y);
                }
            }

            if((move < 0 && facingRight) || (move > 0 && !facingRight) ){
                //control direction character is facing
                Flip();
            }

            if (jumping){

                if(isWallSliding){
                    body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x + 0.25f * jumpForce, jumpForce);
                } else {
                    body.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                }

                if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
                    //if is moving while jumping, reduce jump height
                    body.velocity = new Vector2(body.velocity.x, body.velocity.y*0.8f);
                }
                onGround = false;
                jumping = false;
            }       
        }
    }

    void CheckIfGrounded(){
        onGround = false;
        Collider2D[] collisionResults = new Collider2D[2];
        int objectsBeneath = Physics2D.OverlapBoxNonAlloc(groundCheck.position, new Vector2(0.9f, 0.3f), 0.0f, collisionResults, layerGround);
        for (int i=0; i <objectsBeneath; i++ ){
            if (!GameObject.ReferenceEquals(gameObject, collisionResults[i].gameObject)){
                onGround = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void checkIfWallSliding(){
        if (!onGround){
            RaycastHit2D[] ray = new RaycastHit2D[1];
            int totalRayHits = Physics2D.LinecastNonAlloc(bulletSpawner.position, body.position, ray, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("SolidGround"));
            bool wallFound = totalRayHits > 0 && ray[0].collider.gameObject.tag == "SolidGround";

            isWallSliding = wallFound && ( (facingRight && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) ||  (!facingRight && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))) ;
        } else {
            isWallSliding = false;
        }
    }


    public void Die(){
        dead = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: that didn't work, you editted the part where the character is just jumping (sorry if my code is hard to understand). I tried to apply the same logic where the character jumps from a wall (in the `if (jumping){

                if(isWallSliding){` part) but it didn't work too

Comment: The code in my comments on your question go into the jumping block. This answer's code goes into your air control block (I left the comments that were originally in your code to show where it goes). What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did it not compile? Please be more descriptive.

Comment: It compiled, but the character is still moving away from the wall either so fast the player cant see, or so slow he can't get enough momentum to go up

Comment: To be clear, you will need to use **1.** this answer's change in your air control code, **and 2.** the change in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728147/unity2d-cant-balance-wall-jump-forces/52729903?noredirect=1#comment92383558_52728147) underneath the `//while charachter is wall sliding, slowly fall` comment **and 3.**  the change in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728147/unity2d-cant-balance-wall-jump-forces/52729903?noredirect=1#comment92382865_52728147) where you check for jumping after `if (jumping){ if(isWallSliding){`

Comment: @YuriWaki I edited my answer to include your code with all of the changes I recommended together, in case my recommendations were unclear. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your effort, but it is not working, now the character stopped wall jumping. I really would like to make this work, are you willing to see my screen remotely to help me? I could send you a few bucks through paypal / btc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181631/discussion-between-ruzihm-and-yuri-waki).

Comment: works like a charm, you are awesome! Thank you so much :)